# Script needed: Search entire hard drive for one filename and mail or upload it

Tags: search, upload

I want create a script which searches for a filename on my whole hard drive and if it finds this file, it uploads this using FTP- NOR e-mail-protocol.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't ever run that on my machine.

Comment: Operating System? Scripting language preference?

Comment: @jibsales: Should work on any Windows and Linux. Any programming language is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Linux, you can use the `find` command. It has depth options and with `-exec` you can perform additional actions on the found file(s). In your case you would want something like `scp` or another command to copy the file over SSH or FTP.

```
find -d -mount -noleaf file
```

`-d` looks at contents of a directory before the directory (probably good if a file is in a folder of the same name, so you aren't moving the whole folder with other unwanted files)

`-mount` only searches one filesystem

`-noleaf` makes the search compatible with various filesystem conventions, by not assuming all directories have two hard links. Better details in [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Then connect to ftp (note that your passwords would be visible in the script to connect to ftp). And use `put file`.

Or use `scp -i id_file user@localhost:file user@remotehost:file`. Using `-i id_file` always you to authenticate with a key file that is separate from the script.

**UPDATE:** To be compatible with both Windows and Linux, you could write a "brief" java application. Here is a tutorial on [finding files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) and the [javadoc for FTP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html). What you want is possible in Java, but I don't think it will be easily done in a few lines.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Let me rethink this.

Comment: I am not a fan of Java and my machines are not running Java. Is there any other option without Java Script?

Comment: Updated with some links to explore if you wanted to do this in Java, but I think you would end up writing a whole find function and then FTP the file. I doubt it can be done in a few lines, hopefully someone with more knowledge on cross-platform scripting languages can help you find an answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain there are dozens of options. You could use the PHP filesystem functions, like [glob](http://php.net/glob) to find the file. PHP might be a good option, as it would be easy to adapt into a small web application for you to use in a browser to search your machines. Which would make it easy to vary your search parameters, rather than just searching by filename alone.